# How to import material-ui components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Heavily using material-ui in my app, is there a way to avoid doing imports in each app component like this?

```
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container"; 
....
```

or this:

```
import {Typography, Box, Grid, Container} from "@material-ui/core";
```

Is there such thing like this? So that I don't need to import each component?

```
import * from "@material-ui/core"
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Importing all the components when you actually just need 4 or 5, not a good idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an import all in JavaScript. You can do it like so:

```
import * as Mui from '@material-ui/core';
```

This puts all of the named exports of `@material-ui/core` into the `Mui` "namespace". Then, you can easily access any of the components i.e.:

```
<Mui.Typography>Test</Mui.Typography>
```

You can read more about [`import` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: Also wondering is importing all recommended in this case? Does it slow down the code or cost memory?

Answer (score 3):

The first option is not much clean from an import statement perspective, especially when you want to import and use a lot of `Mui` components, but as you use path imports to avoid pulling in unused modules, gets an optimized bundle size automatically.

The second option (`import * from "@material-ui/core"`), on the other hand, is the most convenient from a development perspective, and also makes you have a clean import statement, but will make your application packages larger than they import each component separately depending on what part of components you are using.
Moreover, there is a large scale application you need to import from different sources of Material-ui:

```
import {} from '@material-ui/core';
import {} from '@material-ui/icons';
import {} from '@mui/material';
```

A better optimized approach, is to create a single file in your project where you import each component that you use individually, then export them all under a single namespace:

```
// src/mui/index.js
export { default as MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
export { default as TextField } from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
export { default as Select } from '@material-ui/core/Select';
export { default as ClearIcon} from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
export { default as FormControl } from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
export { default as Button } from '@mui/material/Button';
...
```

Then you can import that file wholesale into each component where you need it:

```
// ../../MyComponent.js
import {
  MenuItem,
  TextField,
  Select,
  ClearIcon,
  FormControl
} from 'mui';
```

Now you have a clean import statement and optimized bundle size as well.

---

*Working with absolute path*: I never address components with a relative path (e.i ../../../mui). you can take a look [here](https://dev.to/emanuelone/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-reactjs-503i) if you don't know how to use absolute path in React.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this in following way:

1. create a folder called collections
2. create a file called index.js under collections folder
3. write the following code in index.js

> export {default as Button} from "@material-ui/core/Button";
>
> export {default as Card} from "@material-ui/core/Card";
>
> export {default as Paper} from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

4. now import collection like bellow:

> import * as collections from './collections';

**Your component file will be as:**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import * as collections from './collections';

class Box extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <collections.Button>
                    Test
                </collections.Button>
                <collections.Card>test</collections.Card>
                <collections.Paper>test</collections.Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Box;
```

Comment: I see in this answer, the mui components are imported one by one in collection, is there a  reason you didn't import all?

Comment: @Kiki Yes of course, you will not need all material component in your every component. This is just an example how you can group some material component in one package and able to use that package in your specific component. It may happened that some other material component you will need in your another component. So you can build another package like this.